# How to print a form for every row of a loop in Symfony2.

Tags: php, forms, symfony

i want to have a Form in every row with the values: **"accept"** and **"decline"**.

But now, I recognize it is not as easy as in a plain php project, where I can write something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  <tr> 

    <td>$row['name']</td>
    <td>
        <form method='POST' action='action.php'>
            <input type='hidden' value='$row[id]'>
            <input type='submit' value='accept'> 
   </td>
   <td>
        <form method='POST' action='action_decline.php'>
            <input type='hidden' value='$row[id]'>
            <input type='submit' value='decline'> 
   </td>
 </tr>
}
```

I even know, that in Symfony2 it is possible to react with the method `isClicked()` on the various buttons, so I have not to create two different forms in each row.

But my problem is I can only send one form with the controller to the twig-template.

How is it possible in Symfony to generate dynamic forms in list (loops)?

Greetings Michael

Comment: Why do you need two forms for two actions? You can have 2 buttons in the same form sending request to action.php and passing the value of one of your buttons to action.php?value=accept/decline and inside the file you can switch between two actions.

Comment: yes, this is possible, i know. In symphony i would work with isClicked(). Also I have one form. But I want to know, how is it possible to loop with Symfony2 this forms for every row. I see no way because I have only one form from the controller and if i loop the object it would be always the same form - which is causing an error :D .

Comment: If you need two forms in the page load, with different actions, then you need two forms in Symfony2. I don't think there's any way around that. You could create two methods in your controller using 2 different routes, and listening for the same form, but in my opinion that's just bad design.

Comment: Yes, an how you would solve this. I think about using simple links instead of forms... .

Comment: How would I solve this? With the little information you provide, I would go with @Fratyr solution.

Comment: You don't understand my question. I want to know, how I can Iterate (loop) this from my Symfony2 Controller. (whether a form or simple links doesn't matter). I have only one $this->createForm() method. Also I think, I will simple iterate with simple links. Then I can simply iterate with twig-for-loop and set simple the parameters for the routes. My question was, if there is a opportunity to iterate with small forms.